# ROS Answers SE migration: URDF and SDF?

Tags: ros, gazebo, urdf, sdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I've seen a bit of discussion about URDF and SDF here and I thought I'd ask the broad question before I try to learn either of them.

I am developing a natural language processor to split these out (and into simulations) and I should be aware of which one is better for which purpose (scene vs. robot, if that makes sense, even) or if one is being deprecated or something.

Should I be learning one or the other or both?

I'm all ears.

Sincerely,

-Todd

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228873/urdf-and-sdf?/) by [toddcpierce](https://answers.ros.org/users/25497/toddcpierce/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2016-03-12

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While [this document on Gazebo's web site](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_urdf) should answer to the most/all of your questions, I would still comment to:

> which one is better for which purpose (scene vs. robot, if that makes sense, even)

URDF is only capable of describing a single robot (i.e. no scene, no multiple robots).

> or if one is being deprecated or something.

[One of the core Gazebo developers said in 2014 that neither of them is deprecated](http://answers.ros.org/question/147836/is-urdf-depricated-are-there-replacement-sdf-tools/), which I think is still valid as of today.

> Should I be learning one or the other or both?

Though depending on your purpose, I think so in general. With [a lack of SDF to URDF conversion yet](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/1482/sdf-to-urdf-convertor), ROS tools requires robot description to be done in `URDF`.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2016-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2